# Is it possible to redirect sharepoint subsite site to root site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping, redirect

I need to redirect the subsite URL to Root site collection, For example, if I accessed the ~sitecollection/departments means, It needs to redirect to ~sitecollection, Is it possible? or Is it possible to create a virtual as sites/departments? I tried http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=48  this, but I am not clear, Please suggest me some idea to achieve this .

Comment: What is the requirement behind this? Maybe there's another way to solve this because this approach seems a bit unconventional at least.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your master page, this will redirect to root site if user try to access subsite.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
       var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
       var isRootWeb = siteUrl == webUrl;
       if(isRootWeb == false){
        window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
       }
 });
```